# Subset function in R wont work with vector selection

Tags: r, subset

I have this weird problem where I have something like this in my code:

```
#(2,1,6,3)
states.vector <- unique(data$state)
```

I am iterating through the vector to subset data for each value in the "state" column. At some point through my iteration, the following line of code gives me an empty data frame:

```
#When state == 1
data.state <- subset(data,state==states.vector[state])
```

If state is == 1, it means that states.vector[state] == 2. But when I do the following, it works just fine:

```
subset(data,state==2)
```

What is weird is that I used this process multiple times, and it worked fine for the exact same task, with the same format for "data", but with some different values inside.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to use values of `state` as indices in `states.vector`, even though both objects should have different lengths. Look at `length(data$state)` and `length(states.vector)` to get a sense of the problem.

Comment: What is this subset command supposed to do? You condition looks really strange.

Comment: Try `i<-1; data.state <- subset(data,state==states.vector[i])`. I think the problem is that you are using "state" as an index into `states.vector`, but `state` is also the name of a column of `data`. In the second argument to `subset(...)`, both occurrences of `state` are evaluated in the context of `data`

Comment: Can you give us wider context for this problem? I fear this may be the XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

I think jlhoward has already explained what the problem is.

Why don't you use something like the following lines of code to loop through your states?

```
states.vector <- unique(data$state)

for (selected_state in states.vector) {
  data.state <- subset(data,state==selected_state)
  #...
}
```

Comment: Yeah that was it, the variable "state" was interpreted as a column in data.